# How to check how many specific HTML elements are in a page using RSpec?

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, tdd, capybara, rspec3

In Rails 4 feature spec, using RSpec 3 and Capybara, how do I assert if a certain number of specific tags are present in a page?

I tried:

```
expect(find('section.documents .document').count).to eq(2)
```

But it doesn't work, saying:

```
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching css "section.documents .document"
```

Also, is it a good idea/bad practice to test in a feature spec something so specific as the kind of tags and classes used in the view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with using `find` is that it is meant to return a single matching element. To find all matching elements, which can then be counted, you need to use `all`:

```
expect(all('section.documents .document').count).to eq(2)
```

However, this approach does not make use of Capybara's waiting/query methods. This means that if the elements are loaded asynchronously, the assertion may randomly fail. For example, `all` checks how many elements are present, the elements finish loading and then the assertion will fail because it compares 0 to 2. Instead, it would be better to make use of the `:count` option, which waits until the specified number of elements are present.

```
expect(all('section.documents .document', count: 2).count).to eq(2)
```

There is some redundancy in this code and the assertion message will be a bit strange (since there will be an exception rather than a test failure), so it would be better to also switch to using `have_selector`:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('section.documents .document', count: 2)
```

Comment: still valid and useful. couldn't figure out what to search for to find this in the docs